# Where to start with my web app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, web-applications, sinatra

As a learning exercise I want to create a simple webapp - I am familiar with html/css but want to delve into more backend .

My learning objectives for the app are relatively simple:

- Create the app using ruby (as I'm learning this at the moment)
- Learn how to store data into a database
- How to display stored data
- Have the app available online - I was thinking either sinatra or RoR?

I've [uploaded an image of what I want my app to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzuRv.jpg) and do. I am able to make the various input fields and buttons using html and style with css but don't know where to go from there to create a database and link it to the buttons etc.

I'm not after completed code, but rather what I should research and look into. I would appreciate any and all help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the desired app, and given that it's for learning purposes, I'd suggest to pick Sinatra + ERB/Haml + MySQL/PostgreSQL since it's lighter, extremely easy and quick to learn. Once you are comfortable with it, you'll easily be able to move to a more complex framework like RoR.

Some resources to start off: 
http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

http://testerstories.com/building-simple-web-apps-with-ruby-part-1/

http://samuelstern.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/making-a-simple-database-driven-website-with-sinatra-and-heroku/

http://matt.weppler.me/2013/07/19/lets-build-a-sinatra-app.html

If you don't want to get into the complexity of a database, you could even do away with storing your details in yaml file(s). Hope this gets you started.

Answer (score 1):

Best two resources to get started with Ruby on Rails. Start with the first link and use the second to reference.

- http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html